# Hg-Git: How to push to both Github and Bitbucket?

Tags: git, mercurial, hg-git

I just installed [Hg-Git](http://hg-git.github.com/) and I was wondering if it is possible to push to both Bitbucket.org and Github.com from the same repository. I'm thinking of something like:

```
$ #make commits
$ hg push #pushes to Bitbucket since it is set as `default` in hgrc
$ hg push "github remote alias" #push to Github
```

So, by default it pushes to Bitbucket, and to push to Github by specifying a "remote" alias.

Comment: I haven't tried it. Does Hg have a `remote add` command to try this?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you asking how to make the `push` command push to multiple remote destinations?

Comment: See the second exercise here: http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/basic/#id4

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your question is how to make `hg push` able to push to multiple remote destinations, one by default and one named, then that's easy.

You edit the `.hg\hgrc` file in your repository and add/modify:

```
[paths]
default = https://hg01.codeplex.com/mercurialnet
kiln = https://lassevk.kilnhg.com/Repo/Mercurial-Net/dev/trunk/
```

The above is my setting for one of my projects. By default, ie. just `hg push` it pushes to CodePlex, but I can also ask it to push to kiln by executing `hg push kiln`.

The one named `default` is basically the one used if you don't specify the alias for a remote destinations, and you can have 0 or more named ones in addition to `default`.

If that was not your question, please elaborate.

Comment: Is it possible to push to several remote repos simultaneously with one command? I'm just wondering if it possible :)

Comment: @Dmitry: This is possible using [hooks](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#hooks). A `post-push` hook would fit for that purpose.

Comment: @Oben: Thanks for the answer. I'm aware of hooks feature, and I was wondering if it is possible to do without hooks.